# Como selecionar os registros de uma tabela em caixa alta no postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu preciso selecionar todos os registro de uma tabela onde as letras de uma determinada coluna estão em caixa alta(Maiúsculas).
Existe alguma função que faça a diferenciação de maiúscula/minuscula no `POSTGRES`?
Aqui vai a imagem da minha tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna `numero_fci` possui diversos registros como caracteres alfanuméricos, porém, alguns registros estão em caixa baixa(Minúscula) e em um `SELECT` eu gostaria de retornar somente os que estiverem em caixa alta.
Como devo proceder?
Desde já eu agradeço!

Comment: não é por nada, mas você está usando o tipo errado, você está armazenando um [`UUID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html) usando `character(36)`

Comment: E qual seria o jeito certo?

Comment: Eu aconselharia você utilizar o tipo [`UUID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-uuid.html), quanto à formatação, deixe isto para a aplicação (`C#`, `Java`, `NodeJS`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, etc tem suporte à `GUID/UUID`), mas se precisar exibir a `UUID` como texto com caracteres maiúsculos direto no Banco, faça: `upper(numero_fci::TEXT)`

Comment: Ok @TobiasMesquita, valeu pela dica!

Comment: Uma observação em relação ao tipo do campo `character(36)`, é agente não geramos esse código e sim a receita. Agente só armazena as informações do retorno que a receita federal nos dá. Portanto o tipo do campo no nosso banco está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seleciona todos os registros que forem diferentes quando voce os joga em uma função lower. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE LOWER(numero_fci) != numero_fci
```

Comment: Obrigado @Rovann Linhalis, não funcionou do jeito que vc mencionou mais vc pode me ajudar a chegar na solução. `SELECT * FROM fci_item WHERE UPPER(numero_fci) in( select numero_fci from fci_item  );`

Comment: blz, mas acredito que não precise desse subselect